# Getting cookies from a form submit and using them with a webtest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, webtest, cookiejar

So I'm trying to do some test cases with webtest library, the problem is that my site has access control which requires a user to login. It seems that the form post is successful, but the result do not have any cookies (that I could find at least), and the cookiejar is empty after the login.

Test setup:

```
class TestMyViewSuccessCondition(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.config = testing.setUp()

        from myapp import main

        settings = {'sqlalchemy.url': postgresqlURL}
        app = main({}, **settings)
        from webtest import TestApp

        self.testapp = TestApp(app, cookiejar=CookieJar())
```

Test:

```
    page = self.testapp.get('/login', status=200)

    self.assertIn('Please login', page)

    form = page.forms['loginForm']
    form['username'] = 'user'
    form['password'] = 'userpw'

    result = form.submit(status=200)

    # self.testapp.cookies is empty dictionary at this point
    # it fails here, login page is shown again
    page = self.testapp.get('/home', status=200)
```

result returns 200 OK, and the HTML content of the login page, after the form submit, but no redirect is happening, is that a problem? or is that working as intended? Before the any access control other form submits worked just fine. The cookies will change every time when the user clicks a link or reloads the page. I'm using session cookies. I tried to set a unsecure flag for cookies.

and the last return of the my login view:

```
if 'form.submitted' in request.POST:
# do stuff
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
```

I would be using the normal unittest but since unittest module looses its nuts when the view tries to do redirect, someone suggested webtest library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the `form.submit()` didn't actually mimic the basic use-case of mine, where the user clicks the submit button. In normal case the browser adds the username, password and the `('form.submitted', '')` in side of the `request.POST`. But the `form.submit()` only adds the username and password, and only those that are defined in the form, so I couldn't define my own values to go with the request. (at least I didn't found out how)

Problem was solved inside of the login view. by changing the `if 'form.submitted' in request.POST:` -> `if 'username' in request.POST and 'password' in request.POST:`

Cookies are working just fine, as show above, login failed to support my test.